# Polygon position for collision detection won't update? or Collide?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using polygons for a method of collision detection. I have a rock, the moves in a certain direction.

When I run the application, the polygon renders into a perfect rectangle where the rock is when it is started.

Yet, it doesn't **move** *with* the rock.

```
public Polygon box;
private int width;
public int height;
public float [] vertices;

public Rock (float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    position = new Vector2(x, y);
    velocity = new Vector2(20, 0);

    vertices = new float[] {position.x, position.y, position.x+width, position.y, position.x+width, position.y+height,
            position.x, position.y+height};
    box = new Polygon ();        
    box.setOrigin(width/2, height/2);

}

public void RockMove (float delta) {
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));
    box.setVertices(vertices);
    box.setPosition(position.x, position.y);

}
```

sprite batch for rock

```
public void render (float delta) {
    batch.begin();
    batch.enableBlending();
    batch.draw(rock, rock.GetX(), rock.GetY(), rock.GetWidth(), rock.GetHeight());
    batch.disableBlending();
    batch.end();

}
```

And this is some code from a render class

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
shapeRenderer.polygon(Rock.vertices);

shapeRenderer.end();
```

Again, the polygon shows up perfectly, but doesn't move. I don't have any errors.

Edit: I defined the vertices again in the Rock Move method, and now they move with the rock.

```
public void RockMove (float delta) {
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));
    box.setVertices(vertices);
    box.setPosition(position.x, position.y);

vertices = new float[] {position.x, position.y, position.x+width, 
position.y, position.x+width, position.y+height,
            position.x, position.y+height};

}
```

But for some reason, the collision detection won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define vertices again in update instead of you should use transformedVertices of Polygon.

```
Polygon polygon=new Polygon();
float transformed[] = polygon.getTransformedVertices();
```

TransformedVertices is the vertices of the polygon after scaling, rotation, and positional translations have been applied.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out on my own actually.

Comment: That's great :)